# node js require description for '@' symbol for the path?

Tags: node.js, require

What is this @ in the require? can someone describe?

`let bla = require('@/api/blabla');`
what is the "@" symbol means in this path?

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scope

Answer (score 2):

You are probably talking about the [`resolve.alias`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) in Webpack or [subpath patterns](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_subpath_imports) in Node.js? They often resolve to `@` for their src Directory (for example in Vue.js this is used often but is not limited to vue.js).

For example if `@` resolves to the src folder in this structure:

```
my-app/
├─ src/
│  ├─ foo/
│  │  ├─ bar.js
│  ├─ index.js
├─ package.json
```

Those imports from index.js will be the same:

- `@/index.js` and `./index.js`
- `@/foo/bar.js` and `./foo/bar.js`

and from bar.js those will be the same:

- `@/index.js` and `../index.js`
- `@/foo/bar.js` and `./bar.js`

So these operators can help you to navigate in extremely nested directories to find your files.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the package name. Some packages like @fastify/helmet will be written as `require('@fastify/helmet')`

Comment: This can not be a scoped package since the `@` is followed by a `/`and not a valid scope name.